# Rake fails to install on Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cygwin, gem-bundler

We just installed the latest cygwin (setup version: 2.891 - 64bit on the latest Windows 10) and we've installed rvm (1.29.4) and whenever we run `bundle install` we obtain the following error:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
An error occurred while intalling rake (12.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '12.3.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'' succeeds before bundling.
```

A version of the same error appears when simply `gem install rake` and there is no stack trace or further indication of where the error lies. How do I proceed with tracking this down? Is there an error log I should be looking at? Where is the encoding mismatch being generated by `gem install`?

Thanks!

Comment: As you are using windows 10 why are you using cygwin instead of the ubuntu bash already included in windows?

Comment: It's a good question, but mainly it's because of this: https://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/ This is not my system, but a student's and vi or a CLI-based editor is a bit out of scope and (last I checked) the filesystems don't play well together.

Comment: you can always install rake in ubuntu bash and keep the script files in the standard windows file system that you can find under /mnt/drive so you can edit them using the visual editor of your choice

Comment: What is the problem in using the `ruby-rake` package available on cygwin ? https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/ruby-rake/

Comment: Doing the build itself using Ubuntu but using the Windows FS is a creative solution which will probably work well and I may try it, but I'll be disappointed not to be able to tell my student what the true problem was. I can spin it, but it's not ideal. Also, _I_ want to know myself. As for using the Cygwin version, I'll look into it, but I don't think it will give me fine-grained control over the ruby version/work well with rvm, will it? I'll see...